# Error while using Match function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the `Match()` function in VBA code, but it keeps showing me an error and I can't figure out why.

```
stepCol = Application.Match("STEP", Worksheets("op_bank").Range("R1C1:R1C32"), 0)
```

I want `stepCol` to have the column number in the range above that contains the word "STEP".

Comment: "Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using your range argument with A1 type reference. (Range requires A1 style references, or range objects, for arguments).

```
Range("A1:L1")
```

Or use:

```
Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,12))
```